# Google Map library V2 glitches in inflating it at Run time

Tags: android, dictionary, runtime

I have an xml name layout.xml.
my question is how to inflate it at run time ?

```
LayoutInflater mInflater=(LayoutInflater)HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fake,null, false);
maplayout.addView(view);
```

As view does not have "findFragmentById" which map uses to initialize 
like

```
map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Please Help !!

layout.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need to inflate it at run time

No, you do not. You are welcome to [use a `FragmentTransaction` to add the fragment to the UI dynamically at runtime](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions).

Comment: Thanks a tons... do not we have any other option to do it,?

Comment: @Avin: What specifically about using a `FragmentTransaction` presents a problem for you?

Comment: I will tell you yet i did not work for single time on fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You dont inflate it you get the map by calling `GoogleMap map = getMap();` in the fragment in your `onCreateView`

Comment: Yes, I know that but actually I have to use maps two times on same activity for that reason i need to inflate it at run time. But i do not know hot to inflate fragments at run time

Comment: No you either add the fragment to the xml of the activity or use `FragmentTransaction` to add it to the activity's layout. There is no inflating a map

Comment: If you need 2 maps in your activity see this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/03/dual-mapfragment-of-google-maps-android.html